# Responsive Bootstrap Logo Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My logo image look like this on mobile:

[image]

I want it to be automatically smaller so i added this css:

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;

 <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center img-responsive">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600x140" alt="logo" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" />

        </div>
```

But it does not work, can someone help me ?

Comment: Add the HTML to the question as it could be that the parent container of the image has a width greater than the viewport width.

Comment: Can we see the html you are using to contain the image?

Comment: `img-responsive` class should be added against the image itself, not the parent element and in that case you wouldn't need to use your `css`

Comment: Have you removed your `css` for images? If `display: inline-block` is still there the text align will not work.

Comment: Yes i have but it does not work. Only with <center>

Comment: `<center>` element is deprecated. `img-resposive` class is using `display-block` and text align won't work as well. Add `display: inline` for that image. https://jsfiddle.net/js6n3q8d/

Comment: @Morpheus, put your answer in an answer, please. Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/sq03zg4u/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image responsive with bootstrap, you have to apply the class directly in the image

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x140" alt="logo" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.